# What advice do you have for creating the sound of a trolley motor?

Tags: motor-sounds, engine

So far I have created the rumble of the cart and have squeaks of the wheels on the track.  It's the electric whir of the motor that is giving me trouble.  I need the sound to be versatile as the trolley makes frequent stops.  With every source file I seem to run into the same problem, the sound turns into white noise.  I've tried using recordings of a drill and a jig saw, I went to new orleans and recorded the trolley, I've tried using recording of motors from soundcloud and I always end up with a result that sounds more like an airplane than the trolley motor.  Here's a video for reference http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtHROGTHiSk&feature=relmfu .  If anyone has suggestions please let me know, thanks!

Comment: ping me at rcoronado1 [at] gmail and I'll help you out.  I have some recordings that will probably be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just tried something and it worked almost exactly for what you need.  What popped into my head first was that the "motor" sounds kind of like a mid frequency drone, almost like a stringed instrument changing in pitch.  I opened up iris, loaded the violin sample, found a neutral sounding note and slowly modulated the pitch up and down.  If you have a midi keyboard and some kind of sampler try this out.  This will also let you perform the sound to picture for a better result.

I would layer or create some kind of sound that is not exactly a violin, but that sounds closer to that electronic hum/ whine.  When you find a sound you like, layered in with the rattles, bells and other ambiences it should work out nicely.

Comment: Mmmmmm, I like your thinking.  Trying out now, will report back.  

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at underground trains like London's tube.  The trains on the tube are slightly more modern, but if you pitch shift them down a little I think they will work once you add all of the street and track rumble.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8lApzXFvOQ

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I'll see if I can find a clean one to play around with. 